# Find K least values in a Tree in which each node has 4 children

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, trees

Here is an example tree:[image]

Each node has either $0$ or $4$ nodes. The values $v(n)$ of the node $n$ is given by $v(n) = v(\operatorname{parent}(n)) + k(n)$, where $k(n)\in \{2, 2.5, 8, 50\}$, such that a parent has childs of each value. Find the $K$ least nodes in a given tree (always ignore the root node). For our example tree, we get

$K = 4$, values are: $2, 2.5, 4, 4.5$

$K = 6$, values are: $2, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 8$

Parsing all the nodes and sorting is a straightforward solution. But is there a more optimum solution?

In particular, I tried to

- parse the tree fully in a recursive fashion.
- put each node into an array as we parse.
- sort the array in increasing order.
- take the first $K$ values.

If there are $N$ nodes in total, then this solution will be of the order of $O(N\log N)$.

Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @Discretelizard Yes a node can have `zero` or exactly `four`  nodes. Which is why the least `K` values can differ.

Comment: @D.W. I have updated the question with what I tried, which is much more readable. Please ignore the above comment. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is: "Is there a more efficient method than X?"  When I asked what you tried, your response was "I tried X".  So maybe I should rephrase my comments.  What I'm trying to say is that you are posting here a copy of an exercise-style question, and appear to be asking us to solve it for you.  However, that's not really going to help you.  The purpose of exercises is to give you the opportunity to practice, and the benefit comes from you trying to solve it.  So, I encourage you to keep trying.

Comment: Questions where you ask us to solve an exercise for you typically aren't a good fit here.  If you have a specific question about a specific aspect of the exercise (e.g., "I think dynamic programming is possible, and I made some progress, but I got stuck at this specific step, how do I make that step work?") it *might* be suitable.  But better to read the link that I shared, and see how you can use that to make your question a better fit for our site format.